# Pink area on white background on TV screen via HDMI

Tags: mac, external-display, tv

I got a mac mini, and I'm connecting it to a Panasonic-Viera in HDMI.

On an area of the screen, I see light pink when the background is of light color (especially white background). I do not see it when background is dark. Those pink shades are slightly blinking.

- Refresh rate on the TV Viera settings is 100 Hz.
- Refresh rate on the mac settings is 50 Hz / 720p.

I tried adjusting the settings from both the TV and the mac, without any visible improvement.

What is the cause of it?

[image: pink on white screen]

Comment: This looks like interference from a magnetic field Is something magnetic close by? such as a powerful speaker? Try moving them, see if that changes it. If not, it may be that there used to be a strong magnetic field nearby that now destroyed something in the tv. Also, try moving the tv itself to see if that changes the image, just in case you can't find the source of the magnetic field.

Comment: That looks like damage to the LCD panel.  If so, I'm not aware of any way to repair it.  Replacing the panel wouldn't be cost effective.